# A problem with showing that $g_a^2=(-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}p$ for quadratic Gauss sums $g_a$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, gauss-sums

Let $p>2$ be prime, and let $a\in\Bbb Z$. Also, let $\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$ denote the Legendre symbol.

Then let the quadratic Gauss sum be
$$g_a=\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{ax},$$
where $\zeta_p=\exp(2i\pi/p).$ My professor makes the claim that $g_a^2=(-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}p.$ His proof is as follows.

Proof: We will compute the sum
$$\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times}g_a\cdot g_{-a}$$
in two ways.
First,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times}g_a\cdot g_{-a}&=\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right)g_1^2\\
&=\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)^2\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)g_1^2\\
&=\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times}(-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}g_1^2\\
&=(p-1)(-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}g_1^2
\end{align}$$
*I'm fine with this, it makes sense.*

The second way is
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times}g_a\cdot g_{-a}&=\sum_{a}\left(\sum_{x}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{ax}\right)\left(\sum_{y}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{-ay}\right)\\
&=\sum_{a}\sum_{x,y}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\zeta_p^{a(x-y)}\\
&=\sum_{x,y}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)\sum_{a}\zeta_p^{a(x-y)}.
\end{align}$$
Then my professor claims that the sum
$\sum_{a}\zeta_p^{a(x-y)}$
is equal to $p$ when $x\equiv y\mod p$ and equal to $0$ otherwise. *I cannot justify this.*
Specifically, when $x\equiv y\mod p$, $p|x-y$ and thus $\zeta_p^{a(x-y)}=1$ for all $a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$, so that

$$\sum_{a}\zeta_p^{a(x-y)}=\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}1=\color{red}{p-1}.$$
When $x\not\equiv y\mod p$, the map $q\mapsto (x-y)q$ is a bijection $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times\rightarrow (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ and thus
$$\sum_{a}\zeta_p^{a(x-y)}=\sum_{a}\zeta_p^a=\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\zeta_p^{a}=\frac{\zeta_p}{\zeta_p-1}(\zeta_p^{p-1}-1)=\frac{\zeta_p}{\zeta_p-1}(\zeta_p^{-1}-1)=\frac{1-\zeta_p}{\zeta_p-1}=-1.$$
So in both cases, my computations suggest that we should be summing over $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ instead of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$, but I don't know if this will affect the proof.

Did I mess up somewhere? Why am I unable to justify his claim? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to allow for $g_0=\sum_x\left(\frac xp\right)=0,$ at least for $p\neq 2.$

Comment: The addition of $g_0\cdot g_0$ changes nothing, but now all your sums become over $a\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are very correct, the sum $\sum_{a \neq 0} \zeta_p^{a(x - y)}$ is indeed $p - 1$ and $-1$ respectively, as you calculated, and what your professor stated is incorrect. However, the rest of the calculation is correct. you can follow this up, since we can manipulate the sum as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{x, y} \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y}{p}\right) \sum_a \zeta_p^{a(x - y)} &= \underbrace{\sum_x \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^2 (p - 1)}_{x = y} + \underbrace{\sum_{x \neq y} \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)} (-1) \\
&= \underbrace{(p - 1)}_{\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^2 = 1 \iff x \neq 0}(p - 1) - (1 - p) \\
&= p(p - 1)
\end{align*}

And the rest follows! Hope this helps :)

P.S. This proof is presented in Ireland and Rosen's book "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" which has a clear presentation as well, in chapter 8 p.92. I have copied it below:

[image]

Comment: ah okay this works, thank you +1

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is in error. We can fix it, however.

Note, $g_0=0$ follows from the definition, when $p$ is odd, so adding $g_0g_{-0}=0$ in your sum on the left changes nothing.

This makes all your sums over $a\in F=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z.$ Then you see the results the professor states.

When $p\not\mid (x-y),$ the argument that $a\mapsto (x-y)a$ is a bijection applies to all of $F,$ not just on $F^{\times},$ so the same argument follows.